# FBLoginView popup issue

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have an app integrated with Facebook SDK 3.8 for iOS. I am using FBLoginView for authentication. However, the FBLoginView works fine only on some devices. On other devices, I get this pop up. When i tap on OK, nothing happens. Is this related to the devices' privacy settings somehow ? So far, it works on iOS 6 and iOS 7. But not on all the devices.

[image: Pop Up]

Answer (score 0):

Check if on this devices Facebook account is created and stored in iOS Settings app

Comment: This popup is just a part of Facbeook native login. You need to check if your app is correctly configured to use your Facebook app id

Comment: Other devices with the same iOS version and the same Facebook setting in Settings?

Comment: Are you facebook app in sandbox mode?